# CSS Flexbox behaviour

Tags: css, flexbox

My question is simple.
I've got a title on the left (dynamic, it can be much more longer) and next to it an empty div which has just a border-bottom and height properties.

Here is a fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/KCarnaille/apk36s0n/4/

I want my *.empty-div*, **using flexbox properties** :

```
width =  full container width - my title width
```

Without mentionning any css width property of course.

Any idea? Thank you !

Comment: for infos you could use box-shadow or a single hx tag http://jsfiddle.net/apk36s0n/7/

Comment: Interesting indeed, but I simplified the HTML for the example, it's a bit more complicated in my case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the empty div.

```
flex:1;
```

Instead of a width or min-width

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apk36s0n/6/)